# Palette with editable InputField

Tags: inputfield, palettes

I need a `Palette` with editable `InputField`.

When I try the code `CreatePalette[Pane[InputField["Enter a string"]]]` it makes the pallete but all input goes into an open notebook, not into the `InputField`.

I just need a `Palette` with editable `InputField`. How it can be done?

Comment: Palettes seem to be made for buttons, I'm pretty sure you need CreateDialog.

Comment: Care to provide some code to show how `CreateDialog` can be used to address the OP's issue?  It would make your answer more helpful and probably solicit some rep.

Answer (score 11):

The following code should fix the problem:

```
CreatePalette[Pane[InputField["Enter a string"]], WindowFloating -> False,
WindowClickSelect -> True];
```

But as we figured out it is not!

I read all available information about WindowClickSelect and WindowFloating options in Mathematica documentation.

I didn't find any notices that we can't use the options simultaneously. 
I also didn't find any cautions that we can't use the options with Mathematica palettes.

Thus, such unexpected behavior is probably a bug in Mathematica.
I advice to contact Wolfram support team regarding this bug.

Comment: It works! :) Thank you Helen!

Comment: I found strange behavior. When use this option I can't execute a cell anymore (Mathematica beeps). F1 to open help system and Ctrl+S to save the nb doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Try to set the option WindowFloating to False.

Comment: WindowFloating really helps. But when I use these options, another problems have arisen. As far as I understand, now the focus of the palette on the InputFiles. So, when I try to use another Mathematica palette to paste something to the notebook, it is pasted into the InputFiled of the my palette. Moreover, I can't use PasteButton in my palette (Mathematica beeps again). So, even with these options I can't create the pallete that works correctly.

Comment: On Mathematica v11.0, this code runs from a notebook (and works), but doesn't seem to allow the palette to actually be  installed.  The Install Palette drop down menu doesn't recognize the new palette (assuming a WindowTitle is inserted into your code) to install it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can't have everything in one, but maybe everything in 1.5 will be ok:

```
CreatePalette[
  DynamicModule[{string = ""},
   Pane[
    Button[
     InputField[Dynamic@string, String],
     string = InputString["", string],
     Appearance -> None, Method -> "Queued"
     ]]]

  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 11. something this is nice and easy, if you're on Mac. It seems this does not work for Windows.

We'll leverage `` FrontEnd`MoveCursorToInputField `` and `SetSelectedNotebook` to temporarily overcome the `WindowClickSelect` issue.

```
paletteInputField[specs__] :=

 With[{uuid = CreateUUID["input-field-"]},
  EventHandler[
   InputField[specs, BoxID -> uuid],
   {
    "MouseClicked" :>
     If[EvaluationNotebook[] =!= SelectedNotebook[],
      CurrentValue[
        EvaluationNotebook[],
        {TaggingRules, "OldSelection"}
        ] = SelectedNotebook[];
      SetSelectedNotebook[EvaluationNotebook[]];
      FrontEnd`MoveCursorToInputField[EvaluationNotebook[], uuid]],
    "MouseExited" :>
     (
      SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], All, Cell];
      SetSelectedNotebook[
       CurrentValue[
         EvaluationNotebook[],
         {TaggingRules, "OldSelection"}
         ]
       ]
      ),
    PassEventsDown -> True
    }
   ]
  ]
```

This then works (almost) exactly as expected:

```
CreatePalette[
 paletteInputField["asdasd", String],
 WindowMargins -> Automatic,
 System`ClosingSaveDialog -> False,
 WindowSize -> 300
 ]
```

Note the `"MouseExited"` call there. This just passes focus back to the previously selected notebook so nothing wonky happens and moves the selection point for aesthetic reasons.

And we don't lose `WindowFloating` either.

Comment: On Win10 the content of IF is selected but when I start typing it writes to previously used notebook.

Comment: @Kuba ah the joys of the FE. I guess this is maybe a Mac-only solution then. What happens if you stick a `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Selectable->True]` in the `"MouseClicked"` call?

Comment: Nope, same story, guess OS dependent. But I wonder how much use if of that if it will break/interfere with typical palette's buttons which assume `InputNotebook` is not the `ParentNotebook`. Hmm, maybe this boils down  to 'how to create floating dialog' rather than 'editable palette'.

Comment: @Kuba I can get around that one using `"MouseExited"`. The not properly getting focus issue is more concerning to me.

Comment: Another comment, don't feel targeted, I just want to point issues people will likely face because I deal with people who try to break my code on daily basis :) So, first of all `"MouseExited"` is commonly used but still undocumented :(, second, when you move cursor during typing it will switch selection, it is clearly unlike any input field/ text area experience so people will complain / find it cumbersome. Again, not your fault, I know the pain.

Comment: @Kuba yeah I know it's not an optimal solution. But it is, I think, about as good a hack as we can get to avoid explicitly allowing `WindowClickSelect`. That said, it's obviously still a hack.