# How to make a small window for a variable

Tags: dialog-window

During the development of my code I need to change a variable repeatedly to see what the resulting effect is and find out that the code works as expected. However, it is hard to scroll down and up to find that variable and change its value.

When someone clicks on Evaluation menu and then Debugger a small window appears. I would like such a small window for the variable I want to change that is there is always a small windows say on the upper right of Mathematica which I can enter the value of a variable and change its value inside the code I have written.

Is it possible to do such a thing at all?

Comment: `CreatePalette @ Dynamic @ x`?

Answer (score 2):

```
CreatePalette[InputField[Dynamic@x], WindowClickSelect -> True]
```

## Edit

As reported by @AlexeiBoulbitch (see comments), this solution seems **not to work for Windows OS** (it does work for me on OS X, v10.0.2). I actually found a **duplicate [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3008/palette-with-editable-inputfield)** which already mention the problem 3 years ago ... This post also gives the following workaround :

```
CreatePalette[InputField[Dynamic@x], WindowClickSelect -> True, WindowFloating -> False]
```

which unfortunately makes the palette not really useful, as it can be now hidden by any other notebook ...

#### Alternatives

**1. Floating Notebook**

I tried here to create a floating notebook looking very much the same as the palette window.
***Is this working for Windows OS ?***

```
CreateWindow[DocumentNotebook[InputField[Dynamic@x]], 
 WindowFloating -> True, WindowFrame -> "Palette", 
 WindowElements -> {}, WindowTitle -> "x value", WindowSize -> All, 
 Editable -> False, Selectable -> False, ShowCellBracket -> False, 
 WindowFrameElements -> {"CloseBox"}]
```

(Most of the options used here are presented in these [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionsForNotebooks.html)).

It looks like this for me (OSX, v10.0.2)

[image]

**2. Docked Cell**

Instead of creating a separate window, it is possible to display some content at the top of the notebook with [`DockedCells`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DockedCells.html). This should provide here also a useful solution for the OP, as (for some reasons) the problem is to avoid *"to scroll down and up to find that variable and change its value".*

Define any content you need, for example here :

```
mydock = Row[{"x = ", InputField[Dynamic@x, FieldSize -> Tiny]}];
```

and dock it this way :

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
 DockedCells -> Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[mydock]], "DockedCell"]]
```

[image]

To undock :

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], DockedCells -> {}]
```

Comment: I would be grateful if you could also explain, how it works. Indeed, evaluation creates a dialog with the input field in which `x `stays.  What to do next?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Instead of writing in the notebook `x=somevalue`, the dialog lets you directly enter `somevalue`(then you have to validate that with the Enter key in order x is set to that value). You can also write `InputField[Dynamic@x]`in the notebook, this works the same. For some reasons, the OP wanted it to be in a separate window, this is the purpose of `CreatePalette`.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Note that if `x`is modified in the notebook, the value in the dialog (inputfield) is automatically changed to that value also. That means that this separate window might also be useful to easily track the values of some variables during some computation  ...

Comment: This is what I would expect, and this is what, indeed, happens, if I use the `InputField[Dynamic@x] `. However, when I tried to do the same with `CreatePallete`stuff, it astonishingly did not work, and I could neither modify x from the palette, nor evaluate the notebook cell containing x. This is the reason for my question. I have Mma10.0.2 at Win7.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Do you confirm that you also set the option `WindowClickSelect`to `True` when creating the palette ? If yes, maybe it is a system specific problem ?? (I have v10.0.2 but with OSX)

Comment: Yes, I just copy-pasted the above code of yours

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I found a VERY closely related [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3008/palette-with-editable-inputfield) about this problem which seems not fixed, at least on Windows. Is the workaround (`WindowFloating -> False`) changes anything for you ? (However if the window is not floating it is not so useful, it is just another notebook). Let me know the result, I will then edit this post.

Comment: Yes, it does. With such an option the palette works.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Allright. Note that with this option, the "palette" becomes a small notebook, it can now be hidden by any other notebook, which makes it not so useful.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Please see my edit for alternative solutions.

Comment: I like very much your idea with the docked cell, it works perfectly. In contrast, I am sorry to say that the solution with the floating document does not work for me. After a value is added into this quasi-palette and "Enter" is once pressed, the whole work stacks, I am unable to evaluate a cell with x in my main notebook. It is pretty the same behavior that I observed and reported above. It looks like a bug, the more that the problem only shows up in Windows.