# Input field in palette

Tags: front-end, customization

Palette notebooks (i.e. the output of `CreatePalette`) prevent users from selecting or editing in them. This causes hassles when trying to put `InputField` into them.

Now, the heart of this problem is the `WindowClickSelect` is `False`. So I can circumvent it like so:

```
CreatePalette[
 InputField["asdasd", String],
 WindowClickSelect -> True,
 WindowMargins -> Automatic,
 System`ClosingSaveDialog -> False
 ]
```

But that makes my palette just a standard notebook again. Is there a way to use input fields nicely without having to set `WindowClickSelect -> True`?

Comment: [looks like a duplicate: 3008](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3008/5478) The bottom line is one has to be precise about which palette's features are essential and which can be sacrificed to achieve this.

Comment: @Kuba I agree. I'll put my answer over there (I was just waiting a little bit before self-answering this one).